# getOrElse method not being found in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

Attempting to follow example in Sandy Ryza's book *Advanced Analytics with Spark*, coding using IntelliJ. Below I seem to have imported all the right libraries, but why is it not recognizing `getOrElse`?

```
Error:(84, 28) value getOrElse is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
        bArtistAlias.value.getOrElse(artistID, artistID)
                       ^
```

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf 
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation._

val trainData = rawUserArtistData.map { line =>
  val Array(userID, artistID, count) = line.split(' ').map(_.toInt)

  val finalArtistID = bArtistAlias.value.getOrElse(artistID, artistID)

  Rating(userID, finalArtistID, count)
}.cache()
```

Comment: Where is your definition of bArtistAlias? I assume it's a broadcast variable of the type Map?

Comment: `getOrElse` is a member of `Option`. Here since you are already calling `value`. Assuming `bArtistAlias` is an `Option` you can call `bArtistAlias.getOrElse` but you can not call `bArtistAlias.value.getOrElse` as `bArtistAlias.value` is not an `Option`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh getOrElse is also on Map

Comment: If you'd add the declaration of `bArtistAlias ` we would be probably be able to help. Though, it seems that `bArtistAlias.value` is an `RDD` and `RDD` does not offer `getOrElse`function. As Map has no `value` function (afaik) 'bArtistAlias' would not be a map but your `getOrElse` signature implicates that you want to call it on a map. So without knowledge about `bArtistAlias` I am puzzled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only make an assumption as the code listed is missing pieces, but my guess is that `bArtistAlias` is supposed to be a `Map` that SHOULD be broadcast, but isnt.

I went and found the piece of code in Sandy's book and it corroborates my guess. So, you seem to be missing this piece:

```
val bArtistAlias = sc.broadcast(artistAlias)
```

I am not even sure what you did without the code, but it looks like you broadcast an RDD[String], thus the error.....this would not even work anyway as you cannot work with another RDD inside of an RDD

Comment: Thanks Justin, that was exactly the problem!